# Solving circular arrangement problem with k identical and m distinct positions.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 11 chairs around a circular table. In how many ways can we arrange 10 people in these seats?

---

If
**(i)** There are 11 identical chairs placed equally apart around the table

My solution is:

First fix the one person in any of the chair.
Then permute other 9 people in remaining 10 seats.
i.e $10P9$ which is same as $10!$

---

**(ii)** If there are 11 distinctly coloured chairs placed equally apart around the table.

My solution is:

All the chairs are distinct.
So arrangements like
$A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5A_6A_7A_8A_9A_{10}$ and $A_{10}A_1A_2A_3A_4A_5A_6A_7A_8A_9$ would be different.
So it is like linear arrangement.
Arrangement of 10 people in 11 chairs can be done in $11P10$, ways which is same as $11!$

---

**(iii)** If there are 10 identically coloured chair and 1 chair is distinctly coloured.

My solution is:

First fix one person in the coloured seat.
Then permute remaining 9 people in remaining 10 seats.
 
i.e $10P9$ which is same as $10!$

---

The answer key says
(i)$9!$
(ii)$11!$
(iii)$11!$

Consider that I am a semi-beginner and learning this subject.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part I, Fix the empty chair and $10$ people can be seated in 10 identical chairs in $10P10= 10!$ ways.

In part II, by fixing one chair, you have made the chairs in a linear fashion.  Then there are 11 ways a person can be seated, 10 ways the second person can be seated and so on until the last person can be seated in 2 ways to give $(11*10*9...2) = 11!$ ways.

In part III, similar reasoning, by fixing the coloured chair, you have made the chairs in a linear fashion.  Then there are 10 ways a person can be seated in the colored chair and the rest of 9 could be seated in the 10 identical chairs in $10P9$ ways + You can keep the colored chair empty and seat the 10 in 10 identical chairs in $10P10$ ways to a total of $(10.10!+10!) = 11!$ ways.

Comment: But the OP says there are $11$ chairs around the table, not $10$. So it seems to me that there are $10!$ possible arrangements (and the answer key is wrong), thinking of the $11$ chairs as seating $10$ people plus one "dummy".

Comment: Simply one chair is empty, I thought it does not matter that there are 11 chairs for the first part. These chairs are around a circular table and there are 10 people to be arranged in 10  chairs around the table.

Comment: I think I edited my comment while you were responding.  It seems to me the way to treat the problem is that there are $10$ people plus one "dummy", for a total of $11$.  Then $11$ objects can placed around a circular table in $10!$ ways.

Comment: In part I, fix the empty chair.  Then the ten people can be arranged in the remaining ten chairs in $10!$ ways.

Comment: For (iii) I can make someone sit in the distinct chair and permute other 9 people in 10 identical chairs in 10P9 ways OR make no one sit in distinct chair and permute 10 people in 10 identical chairs in 10P10 ways. **The presence of an empty distinct chair make the entire arrangement linear**, so no need to fix someone on any identical chair. Overall ways of arrangement: 10P9+10P10. Is this correct?

Comment: I think you are correct in the first part. There are 10 ways to make someone sit on the distinct chair and 10P9 ways to permute 9 people on 10 identical chairs. Overall ways of arrangement  (10.10P9). Anyway, any good book on Counting and Probability containing problems with solutions?

Comment: Your prior argument is not correct. You will have to multiply 10 to 10P9 and then add 10P10